# Compiler error while compiling the RAPID library on VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, collision-detection

I've downloaded the RAPID library and tried to compile it on Microsoft Visual Studio 2008.
However, I'm getting the following compiler error: *C4430 missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int*
at this code segment (the exact line that produces the error is *int flag*):

```
    class RAPID_model
{
public:

  box *b;
  int num_boxes_alloced;

  tri *tris;
  int num_tris;
  int num_tris_alloced;

  int build_state;

  int build_hierarchy();

  friend RAPID_Collide(double R1[3][3], double T1[3], 
         double s1, RAPID_model *RAPID_model1,
         double R2[3][3], double T2[3], 
         double s2, RAPID_model *RAPID_model2,
         int flag);
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's simply bad C++ code; the function should be declared as

```
friend int RAPID_Collide (..argument list..)
```

(assuming that the function actually returns an int; you should actually inspect the function and see what value the return statements return.. if there are no return statements, the function should be declared to return void).